# Golang Truncating Float32 From Scanner Input

Tags: go, parsefloat, strconv

I am attempting to create a program where you can input a float32 into a scanner, and have the output be a truncation of the float, removing all digits from the right of the decimal place.

Example: 
Input: 6.7777 
Output: 6

The problem I'm having with my code is the ParseFloat conversion is rounding up my number instead of truncating the number.

Example: 
Input: 6.7777 
Output: 7

-This Is My Code-

```
I was asked to remove my code. My apologies for any inconvenience.
```

Any golang savants out there that can help?
I'm starting to think i may be using the wrong functions for my program requirements, can i make this code work? Or do i need to take another approach?
Thank you for any time that can be spared to assist.

Comment: Convert the float to an `int`. Or use [`math.Floor`](https://pkg.go.dev/math@go1.19.1#Floor).

Comment: Thank you for the reply mkopriva, your assistance is very much appreciated.  

I used %.f in an attempt to remove all numbers to the right of the decimal place, manually. 
Before adding the decimal, i had been taught to use conversion characters to keep my code more organized. So i used %f to present the float32 in my printf.

Can you specify where I can use math.Floor in the current state of my code?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/LdyqjbilyvH

Comment: mkopriva you solved my issue!

Comment: I added:  input = math.Floor(input), before the final print function, and it corrected the rounding! Thank you again for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
      1. Need correction in fmt.Printf() statement use %d and cast the 
         input to int(input)       
        
     package main
    
     import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "strconv"
    )
    
    func main() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Printf("Enter Floating Point Number: ")
        scanner.Scan()
        input, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(scanner.Text(), 64)
        fmt.Printf("Floating Point Number Truncated: %d", int(input))
    
    }
    Output:
    -------
    Enter Floating Point Number: 6.777
    Floating Point Number Truncated: 6
```